# Question about common UI design element in popovers / drawer menus

Tags: user-interface

This might be a dumb question but I'm curious what people call this design element I see commonly used at the tops of popovers or drawer menus that usually slide up or down.

It's a short, horizontal bar several points high that is a monochrome color. Below are two examples, the first from iOS' Mail app

example

[image]

Comment: This question is more suitable for [ux.se] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handle or a drag handle. And when it's a small grid of squares (to also indicate that it can be dragged), a lot of people call those grips or grip grids.